# Flex php wrapper

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4

Is it possible to have index.template.php wrapper instead of index.template.html for Flex project? So projects main file builds like MyProject.php 
If yes, how to customize it?

Comment: You're asking a fairly simple question that is easily answerable through a google search. Voting to close.

Comment: I certainyl feel that this is not a trivial question.The point Nemi makes here is, that can the index.template file , which has ant variables and placeholders inside it and is configured by the ant build.xml to be processed , be replaced with a .php file.

Comment: @J_A_X Not true. I googled a lot for answer, at least a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Nemi,

This will require you to make changes to the build.xml for your project in Flex IDE.

There would be a build target node inside the xml, which would be having a copy target , which copies index.template.html to {projectname}.html.

Instead of this, you would require to change it to index.template.php --> {projectname}.php or  "index.php" if you want it that way.

You can find out how to make changes to build.xml in flex by a google search, and then do some reading on ant , and make the changes and test.

I hope this helps.